# Prove or disprove that the set S is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define set $S$ as follows $$S = \left\{ f \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \middle| \forall x \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists y \in \mathbb{N}: x < y \land f(x) = f(y) \right\},$$ where $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of boolean functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$.

Prove or disprove that the set $S$ is countable.

I know that the first part before the |-symbol itself is uncountable, but I don't understand the whole $x$, $y$, $f(x)$, and $f(y)$ part, and how it would change the fact that it's already not countable. Could it not just be ignored? I'd be happy about any help.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ ??

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: This notation means that $S$ is the set of all functions from $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ such that the condition on the right of the $\mid$ holds for $f$. (Ie, such that, for any $x\in\mathbb{N}$, if $f(x)=0$ (respectively $f(x)=1$) then there is a $y>x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(y)=0$ (respectively $f(y)=1$)). In particular, it is actually a strict subset of $S$, so you cannot just ignore the condition

Comment: @Raffaele presumably $x, y\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To see that it is a strict subset, consider the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(n)=1$ for all $n>0$. Does this element lie in $S$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom a candidate is $f(n)=n \text{ mod } 2$

Comment: This condition implies that if $f$ is non-constant then there does not exist $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall m,n \geq N$ we have $f(m) = f(n).$

Comment: @Anacardium this is not true; eg consider the constant function $n\mapsto 0$. but you're right that this is true for non-constant functions

Comment: @Atticus Stonestorm I forgot to mention that if $f$ is non-constant. Sorry.

Comment: @Anacardium I was thinking to the binary expansions of the numbers in $[0,1]$. With that condition repetitive numbers are excluded. Even excluding them, the cardinality of this set is more than countable.

Comment: oops, typo: my first comment should read "strict subset of $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$", not "strict subset of $S$"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will define an injection $\varphi:\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow S$. Because $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable, as you have noted, this will be enough to show that $S$ is uncountable. So, define $\varphi(f)$ by $\varphi(f)(n)=f(n/3)$ if $n\equiv 0\text{ (mod 3)}$, $\varphi(f)(n)=0$ if $n\equiv 1\text{ (mod 3)}$, and $\varphi(f)(n)=1$ if $n\equiv 2\text{ (mod 3)}$. Can you show that $\varphi(f)\in S$ and that $\varphi$ is injective? (Answer given below, but try to do it yourself first!)

---

> To show $\varphi(f)\in S$, let $x\in \mathbb{N}$. We wish to show there is $y>x$ such that $\varphi(f)(x)=\varphi(f)(y)$. If $\varphi(f)(x)=0$, let $y=3x+1$, and if $\varphi(f)(x)=1$, let $y=3x+2$.

> To show injectivity, suppose that $f\neq g\in\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Then there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)\neq g(n)$, we have $\varphi(f)(3n)=f(n)\neq g(n)=\varphi(g)(3n)$, so $\varphi(f)\neq\varphi(g)$ as desired.

Comment: Wait, this is injective? Any two functions that coincide on $3 \mathbb{N}$ will be mapped to the same function, am I wrong?

Comment: @NikitaSkybytskyi not quite: if $f\neq g$, say $f(n)\neq g(n)$. Then we have $\varphi(f)(3n)=f(n)\neq g(n)=\varphi(g)(3n)$, so $\varphi(f)\neq\varphi(g)$. you can think of $\varphi(f)$ as containing a "copy" of $f$, where $f(n)$=$\varphi(f)(3n)$

Comment: Atticus, might as well put this in your answer as proof of injectivity.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom ah, I see, it's the other way around, you take the values of $f$, stretch them and fill spaces with both zeros and ones to ensure that it attains every value infinitely many times. A smart move, but maybe, just maybe not the most straightforward.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri done! Nikita Skybytskyi indeed, exactly

Comment: But how does the whole injectivity part prove that S is actually not countable?

Comment: @DavidAffolter ah! so this is essentially the definition of cardinality; if we can construct $f$ an injection from a set $A$ to a set $B$, we say that the "cardinality" (ie size) of $A$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $B$. this is denoted $|A|\leqslant |B|$

Comment: in this particular case, if we had that $S$ were countable, by definition we would have a bijection $\psi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, and then $\psi\circ\varphi:\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ would give an injection from $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, contradicting uncountability of $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @DavidAffolter I guess I should ask, what is your understanding of the word "countable"? (and have you seen the idea of cardinality more generally?)

Answer (score 1):

This $\mid$ symbol you talk about translates to English as "such that", i.e. you want all boolean functions defined on the set $\mathbb{N}$ **such that** for all $x$ there exists $y$ greater than $x$ with $f(x) = f(y)$. This "such that" part and subsequent condition shrinks the initial set of all boolean functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$, potentially making it countable.

Namely, this condition says that your functions attain every value either zero or infinitely many times, meaning that some functions are excluded from the set, with one possible example being $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x = 1, \\ 0, & x > 1, \end{cases}$$ or the one suggested by @atticus-stonestrom

This is a partial answer not answering the title question, but I think that you'll be able to complete from here on. Hint: present all excluded functions as a countable union of countable sets, depending on how many times they attain the "wrong" value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a way to see this problem is that, with your condition, a sequence isn't in S if 0 or 1 appear a finite amount if time.

So I think you can caracterize $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}/S=\left(\{0,1\}^*\cup \{0\}^{\mathbb{N}} \right) \cup \left(\{0,1\}^*\cup\{1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \right)$

Where $ \{0,1\}^*$ reprsents all finite sequence of $\{0,1\}$ (which is countable), and $\{0\}^{\mathbb{N}} $ and $\{1\}^{\mathbb{N}} $ are countable (carinal $\aleph_0 $), So you get that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}/S$ is countable.

However, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ isn't countable, so you must have $S$ uncountable

Comment: What does "/" mean related to set theory? Or did you mean "\" (exclude)?

Comment: This has several errors. $\{0\}^{\Bbb N}$ is simply the constant $0$ sequence, so it has cardinality $1$, not $\aleph_0$, and similarly for $\{1\}^{\Bbb N}$. Moreover, these two sequences **are** in $S$. Finally $\{0,1\}^*$ is not even a subset of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, let alone of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\setminus S$ (which I assume is what you meant when you wrote $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}/S$).

Answer (score 0):

$$S = \left\{ f \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \middle| (\forall x \in \mathbb{N})( \ \exists y \in \mathbb{N}): y > x \land f(y) = f(x) \right\}$$

The function gives as result any sequence of $0,1$ these are the binary representation of the real numbers, for instance in the interval $[0,1]$ therefore the set $S$ is more than countable.

Comment: This is not quite right, since the two constant sequences **are** in $S$.